# Plotting transformed data in R

Tags: r

I am attempting to plot final results. I have transformed my response variables to

```
expon=^0.2
```

to obtain a regression line which describes the effects.
Rather than illustrating the effects with a curved line, I would like to keep the straight line and put an exponential scale on the y axis. Am I overlooking a section in the help pages?

Relevant input so far is:

```
expon = 0.2 ## best fit for assumptions AND correlation 
tempMin = 0
dmaxDS_Summer_noSO4$response = dmaxDS_Summer_noSO4$TempChange^expon

plot(response[ind & !indClosed&!indLarge]~Sunshine[ind &!indClosed&!indLarge], 
  exp="y",data=dmaxDS_Summer_noSO4,pch=21,col="red",
  main='All Small Sites',ylab="Temperature Change^0.2",xlab="Sunshine Hrs")
abline(a[1]a[5]lwd=3,col="red")
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: What is the question exactly? Have you tried Box-Cox method to determine your exponent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `log` argument of `plot` function. Please see the code below:

```
# Data Simulation
expon <- 0.2 ## best fit for assumptions AND correlation 
tempMin <- 0

dmaxDS_Summer_noSO4 <- data.frame(TempChange  = 0.2 ^ 0:100 , Sunshine = 0:100 %/% 12)
dmaxDS_Summer_noSO4$response = dmaxDS_Summer_noSO4$TempChange ^ expon
ind = seq_along(nrow(dmaxDS_Summer_noSO4))
indClosed = FALSE 
indLarge = FALSE

# Plotting
plot(response[ind & !indClosed & !indLarge] ~ Sunshine [ind & !indClosed & !indLarge], 
     data = dmaxDS_Summer_noSO4,
     pch = 21,
     col = "red",
     main = "All Small Sites",
     ylab = "Temperature Change ^ 0.2",
     xlab = "Sunshine Hrs",
     log = "y")
```

Output:
[image: Plot output]